# Swap element in a list

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
   int array[100], num1, c, n, num2;

   printf("Enter number of elements in array\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   printf("Enter %d elements\n", n);

   for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
      scanf("%d", &array[c]);

   printf("Enter the number to swap\n");
   scanf("%d", &num1);

   printf("Enter the number to swap with\n");
   scanf("%d", &num2);

    printf("%d is swap place with %d.\n", num1, num2);


    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
   {
   if (array[c] == num1)
   {
    array[c] = num2;
   }
   else if (array[c] == num2)
   {
    array[c] = num1;
   }
  }

  printf("The new output will be\n");

        getch();       
        return 0;
 }
```

Hi,I'm doing half way of my code but i have no idea how to continue. 
I'm coding out to swap number in a list. could someone help me out?

Enter number of element in array:
5
Enter 5 elements
2
4
6
8
0
Enter the first number to swap:
8
Enter the second number to swap:
2
8 is swap place with 2.
The output will be:
8 4 6 2 0

How can i input -1 to end program?
example: Enter number of elements in array: -1
output: End program.

Comment: First, you have to find the index of the two numbers you want to swap in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there is no further instructions, you just have to run through your array, and change each occurrence of `8` to `2` and vice versa.

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  if (array[i] == num1)
  {
    array[i] = num2;
  }
  else if (array[i] == num2)
  {
    array[i] = num1;
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry last question. how could i do a -1 to end program?
example: Enter number of element in array: -1 , output: End program

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the array to find where the first and second numbers are located and swap them